# Which Login Manager is this?

Tags: 12.04, gui, lamp, cinnamon

**May someone tell me the name of this Login manager ?**

[image: Which Login Manager is this ?]

Additionally I would like to know :

1. How the background image has been added?
2. How to install this (with  the apt-get command) ?
3. Will this work with cinnamon DE ?
4. Is it resource intensive ? How much RAM and disk space it eats up ?

Note : **Cinnamon is the only DE** I am currently having, which has been installed upon ubuntu minimal having LAMP stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is MDM, Login manager of Linux Mint. You can install it from Mint's repository.
Here is the ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mdm mint-mdm-themes
```

This will install MDM and themes, you'll be prompted to select the default Login manager upon installation so choose MDM.

This will work regardless of your desktop environment, MDM is a fork of GDM so I believe this will not hog up the system resources. I personally use LightDM on my Ubuntu 12.10.

`Login window` is the program shipped along to modify the settings of MDM, you can customize pretty much everything with `Login Manager`.

And for more themes and customization head over to [gnome-look](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=150)

Comment: I currently use LightDM... will MDM replace lightDM or i'll have option to use both... If in case i Want to remove LightDM, will giving this command break anything else dependent upon : sudo apt-get remove lightdm

Comment: You can keep both the login managers but you can use only one at a time, To revert back you can run command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mdm` and select between MDM and LightDM. However removing lightdm will not break anything but you should not remove LightDM if this is the only Login manager on your system.

Comment: my system is server specie and i am comfortable with CLI.. how about i do sudo apt-get remove lightdm and then follow the commands u said above. will this auto configure everything for me or i'll still have to do dpkg -reconfigure ?

Comment: That is fine as long as you are comfortable with CLI. Just remove LightDM and install MDM it will work. There is no need to reconfigure.

Answer (score 1):

The image seems GDM running on Fedora.

Comment: Thanks for ur response, but... i am pritty sure bout KDM and GDM... i strongly believe its not out of these two... havn't still checked weather its MDM as said by Gufran  !

Comment: Are these your own personal settings or are your trying to make them look like that?

Comment: I am trying to make my login manager like the one given in the image. i found that image on imgur.com !

Comment: That wallpaper is the default one from Fedora 17, which comes be default with gnome 3 and it's shell (I noticed it because I use it). So that is GDM.

Comment: Thanks , I Just got to know that MDM is forked from gnome. However i am still unable to get the desired look as in the screenshot. the MDM has near equivalent theme but its not the same.. may u suggest some workout to import the neede configs. ?

Comment: Wow, in that I have no idea. Wouldn't it be easier to install gdm?

Comment: I had GDM while asking the question. Now i am on MDM.. and both of them seem to be so different from the screenshot. unfortunately the image was on imgur so its impossible to find the real owner and ask for it.. lol..

Comment: ok, didn't noted any difference